# Stuck with WiX bootstrapper; it gives "Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package"

Tags: .net, wix

I created a .msi using the WiX Toolset, and it works fine. But the problem is when I want to run the .msi using WiX Bootstrapper project, it gives me the below errors in the log file.

> Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
>    Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>    Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

Here is my WiX Bootstrapper bundle code snippet:

```
 <Bundle Name="BootstrapperHelloWorld" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Arifur Rahman" UpgradeCode="1dd53ea0-e19b-4e89-a85f-97ab912700d3">
     <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

     <Chain>
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\HelloWorld\BootstrapperHelloWorld\Prerequisit\HelloWorld.msi" />
    </Chain>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26634793/1766402

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used `InstallScope="perMachine"` attribute while creating the msi file. And use ForcePerMachine="yes" on bootstrapper MsiPackage Element . But still getting the error

Comment: Can you paste more details from the log file here?

Comment: On my log file I got this message, when I run the exe file on another PC
[1114:0F90][2015-02-13T19:46:38]i101: Detected package: MvcSetup.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
I think that's why I got [0274:1350][2015-02-13T19:47:48]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to install MSI package.
Do I get the error for giving absolute file path on sourcefile attribute..?
and where should I keep my msi and other dependent msi file on the bootstrapper project

Comment: The error for absolute path will only happen when Wix bundle tries to compile your Bundle.wxs file and if it doesnt find the msi in the location you mentioned. That error wont happen at run time. Also if you set the MSIPackage Compressed property, then your msi will be added as part of the bundle exe and not left as a separate file. Do this, then run your bundle and paste the log file of the bundle and also the MSI logs here. The MSI log will be at "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\{logfilename}.log"

Comment: {logfilename} for the MSIpackage will be based on the 
LogPathVariable String Name of a Variable that will hold the path to the log file. An empty value will cause the variable to not be set. The default is "WixBundleLog_[PackageId]" except for MSU packages which default to no logging.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Isaiah4110.
At last I found my exact error on my log file, I used iis:WebAppPool for creating pool but the IIS feature was not turn on , that's why the msi gives the error on other PC.

Answer (score 2):

The error for absolute path will only happen when the WiX bundle tries to compile your Bundle.wxs file and if it doesn't find the MSI file in the location you mentioned. That error won't happen at run time. Also if you set the MSIPackage Compressed property, then your MSI file will be added as part of the bundle EXE file and not left as a separate file.

***Do this, then run your bundle and paste the log file of the bundle and also the MSI logs here.***

***The MSI log will be at "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp{logfilename}.log". {logfilename} for the MSIpackage will be based on the MSIPackage → LogPathVariable - Name of a variable that will hold the path to the log file.***

***An empty value will cause the variable to not be set. The default is "WixBundleLog_[PackageId]" except for MSU packages which default to no logging.***