# WiX 3.9 installer terminating error code 0x80070643

Tags: wix

**Edit: New detailed log posted.**

One of my users reports my installer terminating in error.

I've reviewed other SO posts on this subject, which don't seem to address this particular situation.

My script does specify (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426884/stuck-with-wix-bootstrapper-it-gives-error-0x80070643-failed-to-install-msi-p))

```
InstallScope="perMachine"
```

My user is installing on Windows 10. He is running as Administrator. He has added MyProgram to his anti-virus whitelist. The WiX bundle is compressed (one single installer file). Both the EXE and MSI versions of the installer fail. This script runs successfully on thousands of other PCs.

There IS an occurrence of "Value 3" as suggested by [Rob Mensching](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/).

I would appreciate any suggestion as to what is causing this.

Here's the log: I stripped the prefix "MSI (c) (88:FC)" and "Property(C):" to keep the post under 30K characters.

```
?=== Verbose logging started: 11/27/2016 0:0:11 Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00 Calling process: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\Temp\{6de8c131-a8e0-4c1e-8665-ac804eed35e0}\.be\MyProgram6.exe ===
[0:0:11:753]: Font created. Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

[0:0:11:753]: Font created. Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

[0:0:11:753]: Resetting cached policy values
[0:0:11:753]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
[0:0:11:753]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi
******* Action:
******* CommandLine: **********
[0:0:11:753]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
[0:0:11:791]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2
[0:0:11:791]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi' against software restriction policy
[0:0:11:791]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi has a digital signature
[0:0:11:926]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
[0:0:11:926]: Cloaking enabled.
[0:0:11:926]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
[0:0:11:926]: End dialog not enabled
[0:0:11:926]: Original package ==> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi
[0:0:11:926]: Package we're running from ==> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi
[0:0:11:926]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
[0:0:11:926]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}'.
[0:0:11:926]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
[0:0:12:123]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
[0:0:12:139]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
[0:0:12:139]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
[0:0:12:139]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
[0:0:12:139]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
[0:0:12:139]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
[0:0:12:154]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
[0:0:12:154]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}'.
[0:0:12:154]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
[0:0:12:154]: Transforms are not secure.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\Temp\MyProgram_20161127143932_0_Setup.log'.
[0:0:12:154]: Command Line: ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 MSIFASTINSTALL=7 INSTALLLOCATION=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram REBOOT=ReallySuppress CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\bmowe\Desktop CLIENTUILEVEL=0 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 CLIENTPROCESSID=27784
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{5D56C939-4372-4AE3-B3F1-6DA16BAA806C}'.
[0:0:12:154]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize: ''
[0:0:12:154]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}'
[0:0:12:154]: Product Code from property table after transforms: '{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}'
[0:0:12:154]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
[0:0:12:154]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
[0:0:12:154]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
[0:0:12:154]: Adding new sources is allowed.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:154]: Package name extracted from package path: 'MyProgram6.msi'
[0:0:12:154]: Package to be registered: 'MyProgram6.msi'
[0:0:12:154]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:12:154]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038
[0:0:12:154]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
[0:0:12:154]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
[0:0:12:154]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
[0:0:12:154]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
[0:0:12:154]: Running product '{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSIFASTINSTALL property. Its value is '7'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLLOCATION property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REBOOT property. Its value is 'ReallySuppress'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Users\bmowe\Desktop'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '27784'.
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiSystemRebootPending property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:154]: TRANSFORMS property is now:
[0:0:12:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\Favorites
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\Documents
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\Pictures
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\bmowe\Desktop
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
[0:0:12:154]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
[0:0:12:154]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16
[0:0:12:178]: MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation
[0:0:12:178]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
[0:0:12:178]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:178]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:179]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2
[0:0:12:179]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'user@acme.com'.
[0:0:12:179]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2
[0:0:12:179]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi'.
[0:0:12:179]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi'.
[0:0:12:179]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
[0:0:12:179]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI due to existing external or embedded UI
[0:0:12:179]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\'.
[0:0:12:179]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\'.
[0:0:12:180]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '5.00'.
=== Logging started: 11/27/2016 0:0:12 ===
[0:0:12:187]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: PatchPackage
[0:0:12:187]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
[0:0:12:187]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
[0:0:12:187]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
[0:0:12:188]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038
[0:0:12:188]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
[0:0:12:190]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
[0:0:12:190]: Doing action: INSTALL
[0:0:12:190]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: INSTALL.
Action start 0:0:12: INSTALL.
[0:0:12:190]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
[0:0:12:190]: Running UISequence
[0:0:12:190]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
[0:0:12:190]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
[0:0:12:190]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 0:0:12: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 0:0:12: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:191]: Doing action: PrepareDlg
[0:0:12:191]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: PrepareDlg.
Action start 0:0:12: PrepareDlg.
[0:0:12:195]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:12:195]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
[0:0:12:195]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:12:195]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Bigger textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 19 pixels height.
Action 0:0:12: PrepareDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 0:0:12: PrepareDlg. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:211]: Doing action: AppSearch
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 0:0:12: AppSearch.
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: AppSearch
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: AppSearch 4: SELECT `Property`, `Signature_` FROM `AppSearch`
Action ended 0:0:12: AppSearch. Return value 0.
[0:0:12:211]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 0:0:12: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 0:0:12: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:211]: Doing action: ValidateProductID
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: ValidateProductID.
Action start 0:0:12: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 0:0:12: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:211]: Doing action: CostInitialize
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 0:0:12: CostInitialize.
[0:0:12:211]: Machine policy value 'MaxPatchCacheSize' is 10
[0:0:12:211]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ROOTDRIVE property. Its value is 'J:\'.
[0:0:12:211]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CostingComplete property. Its value is '0'.
Action ended 0:0:12: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:211]: Doing action: FileCost
[0:0:12:211]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 0:0:12: FileCost.
[0:0:12:226]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: MsiAssembly
Action ended 0:0:12: FileCost. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:226]: Doing action: CostFinalize
[0:0:12:226]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 0:0:12: CostFinalize.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OutOfDiskSpace property. Its value is '0'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OutOfNoRbDiskSpace property. Its value is '0'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable property. Its value is '0'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired property. Its value is '0'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining property. Its value is '0'.
[0:0:12:226]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Patch
[0:0:12:226]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Condition
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETDIR property. Its value is 'J:\'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLFOLDER property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding BORDERS property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\borders\'.
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ApplicationProgramsFolder property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyProgram\'.
[0:0:12:226]: Target path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
[0:0:12:226]: Note: target paths subject to change (via custom actions or browsing)
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: TARGETDIR , Object: J:\
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: ProgramFilesFolder , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: DesktopFolder , Object: C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: INSTALLFOLDER , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: BORDERS , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\borders\
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: ProgramMenuFolder , Object: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
[0:0:12:226]: Dir (target): Key: ApplicationProgramsFolder , Object: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyProgram\
[0:0:12:226]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLLEVEL property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:12:226]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: MsiAssembly
[0:0:12:226]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: MsiAssembly 4: SELECT `MsiAssembly`.`Attributes`, `MsiAssembly`.`File_Application`, `MsiAssembly`.`File_Manifest`, `Component`.`KeyPath` FROM `MsiAssembly`, `Component` WHERE `MsiAssembly`.`Component_` = `Component`.`Component` AND `MsiAssembly`.`Component_` = ?
Action ended 0:0:12: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
[0:0:12:242]: Doing action: MigrateFeatureStates
[0:0:12:242]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 0:0:12: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 0:0:12: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
[0:0:12:242]: Skipping action: MaintenanceWelcomeDlg (condition is false)
[0:0:12:242]: Skipping action: ResumeDlg (condition is false)
[0:0:12:242]: Doing action: WelcomeDlg
[0:0:12:242]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:12: WelcomeDlg.
Action start 0:0:12: WelcomeDlg.
[0:0:12:242]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:12:242]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898
Info 2898.For Font10 textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 16 pixels height.
[0:0:12:242]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:12:242]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898
Info 2898.For Font12 textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 19 pixels height.
Action 0:0:12: WelcomeDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:258]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: _RemoveFilePath
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CostingComplete property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: BindImage
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ProgId
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: PublishComponent
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: SelfReg
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Extension
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Font
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Class
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: TypeLib
MSI (c) (88:54) [0:0:12:292]: Note: 1: 2727 2:
[0:0:15:621]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:15:621]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 14 pixels height.
Action 0:0:15: LicenseAgreementDlg. Dialog created
[0:0:17:076]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding LicenseAccepted property. Its value is '1'.
Action 0:0:18: InstallDirDlg. Dialog created
[0:0:27:708]: Doing action: WixUIValidatePath
[0:0:27:708]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:27: WixUIValidatePath.
Action start 0:0:27: WixUIValidatePath.
MSI (c) (88:74) [0:0:27:729]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIE4CF.tmp, Entrypoint: ValidatePath
MSI (c) (88:A8) [0:0:27:730]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (88:A8) [0:0:27:731]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (88:A8) [0:0:27:731]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (88!B8) [0:0:27:767]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID property. Its value is '1'.
Action ended 0:0:27: WixUIValidatePath. Return value 1.
Action 0:0:27: VerifyReadyDlg. Dialog created
[0:0:28:279]: Note: 1: 2727 2:
[0:0:28:777]: Note: 1: 2727 2:
Action ended 0:0:28: WelcomeDlg. Return value 1.
[0:0:28:809]: Doing action: ProgressDlg
[0:0:28:809]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:28: ProgressDlg.
Action start 0:0:28: ProgressDlg.
Action 0:0:28: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 0:0:28: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
[0:0:28:823]: Doing action: ExecuteAction
[0:0:28:823]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:28: ExecuteAction.
Action start 0:0:28: ExecuteAction.
[0:0:28:824]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its value is '1'.
[0:0:28:824]: Grabbed execution mutex.
[0:0:28:824]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
[0:0:28:824]: Switching to server: TARGETDIR="J:\" INSTALLFOLDER="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\" BORDERS="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\borders\" ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram" REBOOT="ReallySuppress" CURRENTDIRECTORY="C:\Users\bmowe\Desktop" CLIENTUILEVEL="0" MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI="1" CLIENTPROCESSID="27784" USERNAME="user@acme.com" SOURCEDIR="C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\" ACTION="INSTALL" EXECUTEACTION="INSTALL" SECONDSEQUENCE="1" ROOTDRIVE="J:\" INSTALLLEVEL="1" WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1" ADDLOCAL=ProductFeature
[0:0:28:824]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi
[0:0:28:824]: Grabbed execution mutex.
[0:0:28:824]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
[0:0:28:824]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
[0:0:28:824]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
[0:0:28:824]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
[0:0:28:824]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
[0:0:28:824]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
[0:0:28:824]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied. Counter after decrement: -1
[0:0:28:824]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
[0:0:28:824]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied. Counter after decrement: -1
[0:0:28:824]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 0:0:28: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
[0:0:28:824]: Doing action: FatalError
[0:0:28:824]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: ActionText
Action 0:0:28: FatalError.
Action start 0:0:28: FatalError.
Action 0:0:28: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 0:0:31: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 0:0:31: INSTALL. Return value 3.
[0:0:31:489]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (88:A8) [0:0:31:489]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
UpgradeCode = {A2F60910-A7FC-4B96-9375-EFBED25CC826}
WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1
LicenseAccepted = 1
TARGETDIR = J:\
ApplicationProgramsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyProgram\
INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\
BORDERS = C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\borders\
WixUIRMOption = UseRM
WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLFOLDER
ALLUSERS = 1
ARPNOMODIFY = 1
ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
SourceDir = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\
ARPPRODUCTICON = icon.ico
ARPHELPLINK = http://MyCompany.com/customer-support/forum.aspx
ARPURLINFOABOUT = http://MyCompany.com/products/family-tree-charts.aspx
ARPCOMMENTS = Genealogy charts
WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT = Launch MyProgram
WixShellExecTarget = [#cc.exe]
ApplicationFolderName = CC Folder
WixAppFolder = WixPerMachineFolder
Manufacturer = MyCompany Inc.
ProductCode = {64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}
ProductLanguage = 1033
ProductName = MyProgram
ProductVersion = 6.4.29
DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
WixUI_Mode = InstallDir
ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\Temp\MyProgram_20161127143932_0_Setup.log
PackageCode = {5D56C939-4372-4AE3-B3F1-6DA16BAA806C}
ProductState = -1
PackagecodeChanging = 1
ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
MSIFASTINSTALL = 7
INSTALLLOCATION = C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram
REBOOT = ReallySuppress
CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\bmowe\Desktop
CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI = 1
CLIENTPROCESSID = 27784
VersionDatabase = 200
MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
VersionMsi = 5.00
VersionNT = 1000
VersionNT64 = 1000
WindowsBuild = 14393
ServicePackLevel = 0
ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
MsiNTProductType = 1
WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
WindowsVolume = C:\
System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
RemoteAdminTS = 1
TempFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\Temp\
CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
AppDataFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\
FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\Favorites\
NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
PersonalFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\Documents\
PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
RecentFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
SendToFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\
MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\bmowe\Pictures\
AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
GPTSupport = 1
OLEAdvtSupport = 1
ShellAdvtSupport = 1
MsiAMD64 = 6
Msix64 = 6
Intel = 6
PhysicalMemory = 16301
VirtualMemory = 5587
AdminUser = 1
MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
LogonUser = bmowe
UserSID = S-1-5-21-114060400-2668483893-1887058888-1001
UserLanguageID = 1033
ComputerName = DESKTOP-HFEVCA8
SystemLanguageID = 1033
ScreenX = 3440
ScreenY = 1440
CaptionHeight = 23
BorderTop = 1
BorderSide = 1
TextHeight = 16
TextInternalLeading = 3
ColorBits = 32
TTCSupport = 1
Time = 0:0:31
Date = 11/27/2016
MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.6.1586.0
MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 10.0.14393.0
RedirectedDllSupport = 2
MsiRunningElevated = 1
Privileged = 1
USERNAME = user@acme.com
DATABASE = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi
OriginalDatabase = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\MyProgram6.msi
SOURCEDIR = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{64400B50-1EA4-463A-92CB-A13BFE7ED737}v6.4.29\
VersionHandler = 5.00
UILevel = 5
ACTION = INSTALL
EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
ROOTDRIVE = J:\
CostingComplete = 1
OutOfDiskSpace = 0
OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
INSTALLLEVEL = 1
WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID = 1
=== Logging stopped: 11/27/2016 0:0:31 ===
[0:0:31:495]: Note: 1: 1708
[0:0:31:495]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:31:495]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708
[0:0:31:495]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error
[0:0:31:495]: Note: 1: 2228 2: 3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709
[0:0:31:495]: Product: MyProgram -- Installation failed.

[0:0:31:496]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: MyProgram. Product Version: 6.4.29. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: MyCompany Inc.. Installation success or error status: 1603.

[0:0:31:496]: Grabbed execution mutex.
[0:0:31:497]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
[0:0:31:497]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 11/27/2016 0:0:31 ===
```

Comment: You need to look at the log for the msi install that failed it will be here `C:\Users\bmowe\AppData\Local\Temp\MyProgram_20161127143932_0_Setup.log`. This will also be where you want to search for `value 3`. You linked the bundle log `MyProgram_20161127143932.log` which should be used as a way to quickly find the package that had an issue.

Comment: I've asked my customer for a copy of the log file. I hope he hasn't lost interest or patience  :o)

Comment: I've edited the post to replace the first log with the verbose log.

Comment: Can anybody please suggest why the installation is failing?