# Installer '.msi' Not Working Which Is Created By Using WIX

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I have one add-in project that uses a WIX tool to create an installer.
Previously, I was making '.exe' which was running fine.

But now requirement is changed due to security concerns.
Now I want to create '.msi' file.

WIX gives me '.msi' successfully at 'C:/Path/To/MSI/addin.msi'.

But when I try to install the add-in by double-clicking on it, It's giving me an error :

[image]

When I try to hit command **'C:/Path/To/MSI/addin.msi'** in CMD with administrator privileges, It works fine.

After Sometimes, I have found that created msi doesn't having revision number in properties.

[image]

Don't know how to add it & What value should come in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrapper projects produce bundle .exes. They cannot produce .msi packages. If you must deliver only one .msi, you'll need to combine the `MsiPackage`s in your bundle into one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like setting elevated privilege, scope + admin image can be helpful for you. Better to set all of them as shown, but if you have some restrictions about scope or so, just try different combinations.

```
 <Package InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes" InstallScope="perMachine">
```

Comment: Thanks. But can i achieve this in bootstrapper project?

Comment: seems like yes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613030/wix-burn-bootstrapper-not-asking-for-admin-rights-for-my-msi. If you'll pack your msi with that properties to bootstrapper it will work